# What does it mean "the battery is sound"?

Tags: meaning

The whole sentence goes: "Ensure the battery is sound before leaving the site."

I don't know a lot about batteries...

Could this mean that the battery has a specific sound if they press a button on it just to check if it works properly before usage?

Comment: You probably have heard a phrase "[safe and sound](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/safe-and-sound)" used when describing someone's condition :)

Comment: What kind of battery? "Battery" has multiple meanings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two words spelled "sound"  One is to do with noise, it is used as a noun and a verb. The other word means "Healthy" or "Solid and secure", and is used as an adjective. See [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sound#Adjective).

It is the adjective that is being used here.

> Make certain the battery is working, and fixed in place before leaving the site.

It doesn't say how they do this. But it has nothing to do with making a noise.

It is just a coincidence that the words are spelled the same. The word that means "noise" came to England with the Normans and is ultimately from Latin. The word meaning "healthy, secure" is from Old English and has Germanic roots.

(There are actually two other words spelled "sound". One is a noun meaning "a narrow part of the sea", the other is a verb meaning to find the depth of some water.)

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer I have learned a lot about this word!

Comment: There's also the use as a verb meaning to make noise, e.g. to sound a horn, or the sounding of hounds in chase.

Comment: The verb is cognate with the noun, so it is not a coincidence that they are pronounced the same. But edited to mention the verb, thanks.